# How to change the number of equations to the desired effect?

Tags: equations, numbering

[image]
How to change the number of equations  to the desired effect?
for example , (1-4)

Comment: There are 4 close votes already but I don't see how any of the answers in the linked question help this question. There 1-4 means equation 4 in section 1, here the requirement is a compression of a number range (like cite) for equations1,2,3,4. the coding will be entirely different,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I was unsure about this first, but how do you know?  It seems there's just a single equation, so it should just have a single number, maybe prefixed by the section number.

Comment: @jarauh well that's the way I read it:-) Now you ask it could be read the other way, but seems premature to close without asking in any case.  I'll add an answer assuming range, see what happens:-)

Comment: voted to re-open as I stated in comments before it was closed that I was preparing an answer. (@OSjerick)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I agree, as long as we don't know we shouldn't judge, so "how do you know" was the wrong question.  What I should have written and what is my opinion now: From reading the question and the image (given my very limited Chinese, ahem) it is now clear to me that the question is a duplicate.  The "-" confused me first, but now I see this just as an argument to not use "-" in equation numbers, since it is ambiguous.  I agree, though, that the question you are trying to answer is much more interesting.  In any case, I don't have the privilege to vote to re-open.